# Required Attribute throwing an error even for non-empty strings [ASP.NET Core]

Tags: asp.net-core, validation, model, data-annotations

I am validating a model which requires one of the fields to be non-empty. So I am giving a required attribute to that field. However, even when the field is not empty, there is an error. Why?!

```
[Required]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Am I missing something?

My code in the view page

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control @(ViewData.ModelState["FirstName"]?.Errors.Count > 0 ? "is-invalid state-invalid" : "is-valid state-valid")" asp-for="FirstName" name="FirstName" placeholder="First Name" value="@Model.FirstName">
    <div class="mb-2"></div>
    <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="FirstName"></span>
</div>
```

Even in ModelState, I can see the field is Invalid even though the field value is there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call ModelState.Clear() to clear the ModelState value,like this :

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Test(Test  test)
        {
            ModelState.Clear();
            test.FirstName = "testName";
            return View(test);
        }
```

Model:

```
public class Test
    {
    
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: But I want the required validation. FirstName can not be empty. If I clear the model state then, there will be no validation. I have big model. I cannot clear the model state and assign all fields again

Comment: Never mind, my model which was passed was empty. So I had to get the model from the database and use ModelState.Clear() for the passed one and validate the database one. Thanks!

Comment: Did you submit the data and then judge whether it is empty, if it is empty, give the corresponding error?